# How to quickly select other weapon for a slot in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I often want to select a different weapon in a slot, but often I'm too lazy, or don't have time to go to the menu and do it.

For example, when I play as Demoman, if I want to quickly get to the capture point, I use Splendid Screen, but if I defend something, I need Scottish Resistance.

I was wondering if there is some kind of console command that I could bind to a key to change a weapon selection quickly.

This would be especially interesting to use in class-specific config files, such as *demoman.cfg*

Comment: Do you already know about the loadout quickswitch key binding? You can find this in the keyboard options. Holding a certain key will bring up a mini loadout menu for the current weapon slot.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro: This is quite nice, but sometimes can be more confusing than loadout change menu.

Comment: As a person who is constantly changing loadouts (including hats) as Spy, if there were a way to automate it, I would have done it by now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no console commands to change the loadout selection, so there is no way to presets using the .cfg files.

The only way of changing loadout is through the loadout or (as @The Annoying Pyro said) the mini loadout screens.

Loadout saving has been added allowing you to save multiple configurations for different situations. But you must be in the spawn area to swap.